# What is the easiest method to create a gas/fuel hose (see image)

Tags: edit-mode

I want to create the look of a long gas/fuel hose which not only is on the side of the gas pump but also is partly on the ground (see image below) as it is very long to allow refueling of boats. The object I am trying to model is a gas pump on a dock used to refuel boats. I have never works with curves before and can only find one Youtube tutorial which shows me one method to do this and I am wondering is it the easiest method which is as follows -
(edit mode) add a mesh cube
merge to one vertex
extrude in various directions to get the rough 'outline' of the entire hose (that seems possibly difficult to get it to look reasonably correct)
convert to double vertices (ctrl + b + v)
(object mode)  convert to curve (in the convert tab) and change geometry depth and resolution to my liking

I have already modelled the gas pump body and the 'nozzles'.
If in fact it is the easiest method I will use it and try my best to reproduce the correct 'look'.

[image]

[image]

my work in progress gas pump using method by Gordon

[image]

Comment: You could also directly start with a curve object instead of doing it with a mesh which you then have to convert to a curve.  You can even draw curves on a surface (the floor for example).

Comment: Thanks Gordon (always to my 'rescue') however I am not sure what you mean by "start with a curve object" (what object?). And yes I want the curves to be both vertical (down the side of the pump) and horizontal (along the ground). I am assuming that the method I described is quite ok.

Comment: Could it also be just a single 'line' drawn and then cuts added and then select one vertice  at a time  and move it using G and then drag with the mouse?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can do it your way for sure, I was just giving a different idea... which is an indicator for this question probably getting closed for pulling mostly "opinion-based" answers, since there is no single correct solution. To your questions: What object? Well, the one that is supposed to be the hose. And "start with a curve" means, if you want to add an object which should become the hose, instead of `Shift`+`A` > _Add_ > _Mesh_ and then choose a mesh object, you could choose _Add_ > _Curve_ > _Bezier_ for example...

Comment: Thanks.  Yes add curve bezier is something I also saw which I will experiment with.  I don't think it will be easy (for me) regardless of my method or your alternative. I will have a go and maybe learn some stuff.

Comment: It would be great if in Blender I could just draw a line using the mouse with left button held down like I would in an image editor (yes image editors are only 2D).

Comment: As I said in my very first comment: you can even draw curves on a surface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw a curve on a surface, do the following:

1. Add a curve object with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add* > *Curve* > *Bezier*, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> (if not already selected), then <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Vertices*.

   [image: prepare curve object]
2. While still in *Edit Mode*, select the *Draw* tool on the left (if you cannot see the tools, press <kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the *Toolbar*) but do not confuse it with the *Annotate* tool (the other pencil icon above) and set the *Method of projecting depth* to *Surface*.

   [image: draw tool]
3. Draw the curve onto the objects where you want it by pressing the left mouse button and dragging it over the surfaces. Afterwards you can give the curve depth and resolution, but you have to re-adjust the positioning a bit since the curve you draw is directly on the surface without any thickness.

   [image: draw onto surfaces]

Comment: Note that to add thickness to the curve you then have to go into the Bezier Properties in eiher Object or Edit mode (click the green curve icon on the R/H Properties tab). Then open the Geometry entry on the properties panel and increase the Bevel > Depth setting slightly to give the 'hose' the thickness that you want.

Comment: @JohnEason I guess he knows that because it's already part of his question that he was going to do that.

Comment: I though it worth mentioning because a lot of folks have problems finding that setting. You rather lose sight of the original question after so many comments! :^)

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the illustrated method. I considered that bezier curve was the 'way to go' after you previous reply and watching a Youtube tutorial.  Thanks too to John - much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry this has led to another question which relates to drawing and that is once I have drawn (my hose) and I then need to 'drag' areas to different locations I don't have enough 'vertices' to select and so what is the method to add extra 'vertices' (to allow 'dragging'?  I have added an image to the initial question with arrows to what I assume are existing vertices

Comment: @JohnArnold You can select control points in parts of the curve and like on a mesh object, right-click and choose _Subdivide_ to create control points inbetween the existing ones. The tool options menu on the bottom left allows you to increase the _Number of Cuts_, i.e. the number of points you add between.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. My mind went a complete blank re subdivide and all I could think of was try and add loop cuts.

Comment: That would have to be the easiest method to create a realistic looking gas pump hose which is on two different surfaces IMHO. Love it!  I have added an image of my (low poly) gas pump above (not yet complete)  Thanks again Gordon